# Gemfile lock merge conflict

Tags: git

I am performing a git pull from my master branch to one local machine with my application and it is giving me a merge conflict error in my Gemfile lock.

How can i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed your version of the Gemfile. Someone else changed the same Gemfile on master.

Now git has no way to decide whether you want to keep your version, or if you want to go with the master version, or only partly go with the master version.

Did you change your Gemfile on purpose?

If yes, probably `git mergetool` will help you solving your conflicts.

If no, you can simply throw away all your changes with `git reset --hard @{u}`.

Comment: When you say throw away all your changes, do you mean changes to the gemfile?